# How to login Yii2 without database?

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I need a help!

I have a working mechanism login with **DB** but sometimes i need get login process **without DB** (fake user use).

Static method in **User** model

```
public static function findByRoot()
{
   $arr = [
      'id' => 100,
      'created_at' => 1444322024,
      'updated_at' => 1444322024,
      'username' => 'vasya',
      'auth_key' => 'aagsdghfgukfyrtweri',
      'password_hash' => 'aa2gsdg123hfgukfyrtweri',
      'email' => 'some@email',
      'status' => 10,
    ];
    return new static($arr);
}
```

I too tried alternative variat method like:

```
public static function findByRoot()
  {
    $model = new User();
    $model->id = '1000';
    $model->username = 'vasya';
    $model->status = 10;
    return $model;
  }
```

`Yii::$app->getUser()->login()` requires implements from **UserIdentity**

Do auth:

```
\Yii::$app->getUser()->login(User::findByRoot());
```

If I put real name from db in `login` method it returned `TRUE` and that's OK

But if put `User::findByRoot()` (the same object) it  returned too `TRUE` but `Yii::$app->user->identity` has `NULL`

What's problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Yii::$app->user->identity` returns `null` in case it can't find user's id. To fix that, first of all make sure, you supply the right id here:

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    // dump $id here somehow, does it belong to the static collection?
    return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
}
```

Second option you have, is to always return the instance with filled data, since you use a fake data to test it anyway.

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    // just ignore the $id param here
    return new static(array(
        'updated_at' => '...',
        'username' => '....',
        // and the rest 
    ));
}
```